# Is it possible to run StyleCop when I save source with Visual Studio2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I always do `run StyleCop` of menu or build the project when I have used StyleCop.
I want to run StyleCop when the program has been saved.

Is it possible?

Comment: I work with StyleCop for just a few months but I never heard such a setting. I don't think it is exist.

Comment: If you are using ReSharper, you can integrate StyleCop to R#. This will define new rules for R# which then are checked during implementation.

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately, I can't use ReSharper.

Comment: @ko2ic you can [use an add-in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27943466/1207195) (you have a specific event when a document is saved). Of course code is pretty raw and (if you feel you need it) you may handle more special cases (no StyleCop for support non-code files, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately macros have been dropped but to write an add-in is pretty easy. First of all create a new C# Add-In project (when finished you'll need to deploy your DLL into Visual Studio AddIns folder and restart VS).

Edit generated template to attach to `DocumentSaved` event:

```
private DocumentEvents _documentEvents;

public void OnConnection(object application,
                         ext_ConnectMode connectMode,
                         object addInInst,
                         ref Array custom)
{
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
    _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
    _documentEvents = _applicationObject.Events.DocumentEvents;
    _documentEvents.DocumentSaved += DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved;

}

public void OnDisconnection(ext_DisconnectMode disconnectMode,
                            ref Array custom)
{
    _documentEvents.DocumentSaved -= DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved;
}
```

Your `DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved` method will just need to invoke right VS command (please note command name varies with Visual Studio version you're using).

```
private void DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved(Document Document)
{
    document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RunCodeAnalysisonSelection", "");
}
```

In this case you'll run Code Analysis only on current project (assuming it's what you saved then it's also what you want to test). This assumption fails for Save All so you may need to use `"Build.RunCodeAnalysisonSolution"`. Of course there is a lot of space for improvements (for example when multiple *near* sequential saves occur).

If you're targeting VS 2013 then you *shouldn't* use AddIns because they have been deprecated in favor of Packages. You have same thing to do but you have that notification through `IVsRunningDocTableEvents`. Override `Initialize()` in your `Package` (that will implement `IVsRunningDocTableEvents` interface). Call `AdviseRunningDocTableEvents()` from `IVsRunningDocumentTable` (obtain with `GetService()`) and you're done.

Finally note that same technique applies also for any other event (after successful build, before deployment, when closing solution, and so on).

Comment: Visual Studio add-ins are deprecated in Visual Studio 2013. I may need to make VSPackage extensions. But I don't know it. How do I rewrite the above code?

Comment: @ko2ic I hope you're ready for COM style events! You have same notification through [IVsRunningDocTableEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents3.onbeforesave.aspx). Override `Initialize()` in your `Package` (that will implement `IVsRunningDocTableEvents` interface). Call `AdviseRunningDocTableEvents` from `IVsRunningDocumentTable` (obtain with `GetService()`) and you're done (but I admit with packages things are even more complicate).

Answer (score 1):

I made `VSAutoBuild` in reference to answer of @Adriano Repetti.

It has been published in the following URL:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f0930864-0637-4fb3-a34a-155375aa85b3

and github URL:
https://github.com/ko2ic/VSAutoBuild

Comment: But this is autobuild. I do not want to build. just run StyleCOp